# Detect reverse engineering using debugger

Tags: reverse-engineering

**Problem**: Someone has acquired a copy of Company X's application and is reverse engineering it on his network using a debugger. How can Company X possibly detect this activity?

**Further Questions**:

1. Is there a way we can be notified when someone tries to disassemble the application?
2. Is there a way to lock disassembling altogether, like encrypt the file?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: If they don't let it access the Internet, there is no way to be notified.

Comment: Hi, I'm a moderator. If this is from a book, like I said before, we can help, but you need to at least try to answer the questions yourself.

Comment: The reason why I think this is from a book is because you swap from "debugger" to "disassembly" mid-question, and those are very different concepts and it's odd that one would naturally transpose from one to the other. It does make more sense if you are referencing a book and they changed concepts and context and you got confused. So, I'm asking about the book to help you find the context and resolve what looks to be a deeper confusion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a way we can be notified when someone tries to disassembly the application?

No, especially not for a pure software system. Disassembly (as opposed to debugging, which is different) is almost always a process performed "offline", in the sense that the application isn't currently executing. If your code isn't running, you can't do anything on that computer. It might also be performed offline in the sense that the computer being used for the reverse engineering isn't connected to the Internet, or at least is filtering its outbound traffic, so you wouldn't get the notification anyhow.

> Is there a way to lock disassembling altogether, like encrypt the file?

Also no. The code has to be in the correct form (e.g. not encrypted) to execute on the CPU, which is the same form that decompilation tools look for. You can encrypt the entire program except for a tiny bit at the start that decrypts everything else, but you can't prevent somebody from reverse engineering that tiny bit, figuring out what encryption key and cipher it's using, and using them to decrypt the rest (still all "offline"). Alternatively, it's possible to run the program and debug it while it's running, in which case you'll both see the decryption process and the decrypted code as it is written to RAM, and later runs across the CPU.

> How can company X possibly detect [reverse engineering using a debugger] activity?

There is no reliable way. There are simple things you can do, like ask the OS whether there's a debugger attached (e.g. on Windows, the [`IsDebuggerPresent`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/debugapi/nf-debugapi-isdebuggerpresent) API), but there are simple things an attacker can do to circumvent this, such as run the debugger at the kernel or hypervisor level, or stub out or jump over the call to `IsDebuggerPresent` before it executes. More complicated techniques will nonetheless have bypasses as well. There's also the question of what to do if you do detect it. You can exit the process, but the reverse engineer can start it again and try to bypass the exit trigger this time. You can try to destroy the files on disk, but the reverse engineer will have backup copies and also might not let your process write to its install location. You can try to "phone home" to the company, but the reverse engineer is probably using a VM without Internet connection, or at least with filtered access to the Internet.

---

So, what *can* you do? Well, if you insist, there's a few options...

1. Obfuscate the binaries. There are multiple commercial (and some free) tools for doing this. It's not very good protection - e.g. some of them do the encryption step you suggested, which is vulnerable to the bypass I described - but it's at least a speed bump that makes reverse engineering take more effort.
2. Require the software to continually "phone home" in order to execute. This makes it harder to run it disconnected (the reverse engineer would need to skip over all phone-home steps, in a way that doesn't break the program) and also provides a channel for communicating process status. You can even do things where small parts of the code (e.g. cryptographic or API keys, array indices or branch offsets given a particular state, etc.) are basically missing from the binary and need to be provided over the Internet; a reverse engineer might be able to follow along on a "clean" run and patch those in, but it would make things harder (especially if the communication was using TLS with a pinned certificate such that it couldn't easily be monitored). It also makes the UX for your legit users worse; now their program stops working if they lose Internet connectivity, or if your servers are down for some reason, or so on.
3. Use a hardware dongle. Ship your software with a piece of hardware (probably plugs into the USB port) that serves as an out-of-band parallel processor (basically a tiny computer with its own CPU, RAM, and storage, where part of the software resides) or a hardware security module (a hardened store for cryptographic keys or other secrets, which can use them but won't ever divulge them), or both. Make the software depend on that hardware and the secrets it holds. This lets you move some secrets out of the binaries/RAM/CPU on the user's actual computer, which will impair debugging somewhat. On the other hand, the program still needs to know how to communicate with the dongle, so a reverse engineer could find that and spoof it (e.g. ask the HSM to decrypt or HMAC some data "offline" same as the program does while executing normally). This obviously means it's impossible to download your software so you have to distribute it physically, raises unit costs from the usual ~nothing for pure software, and imposes inconveniences and restrictions on your legitimate users (what if they're on a very small laptop without a spare USB port? What if they're in a corporate environment that disallows external hardware? Actually, that last one will probably already have balked at phone-home requirement at all...)
4. You could ship your program entirely as embedded software on dedicated hardware. Instead of shipping software binaries (with or without dongles), you ship an "appliance" that is a sealed computer which connects directly to the user's input devices and monitor or other output devices. Obviously this doesn't work if your software needs to interact with anything else on the computer where it runs, because there isn't anything else ("the computer where it runs" is what you shipped, not user hardware) and makes it deeply inconvenient to use and expensive to manufacture, but it can be done. Note that it's still far from perfect security, though; it's possible to seal hardware in a way that's more tamper-resistant than software, but there are hardware reverse engineering techniques to bypass that too, using things like grinding tools, acids, EM monitors that can detect binary signals on wires at a short distance, hardware debugging tools such as JTAG, electron microscopes that can be used to analyze the silicon circuitry of custom chips, and so on. (These measures also apply against dongles, of course.) It's a game of cat-and-mouse, where you can keep raising the bar (at increasingly great expense to yourself and your customers) but there's no level that *can't* be defeated; it's just a matter of how much you want to make reverse engineers work for it.

---

So... what ***SHOULD*** you do?

None of that. Skip all that futile effort on blocking reverse engineering, and make it a non-issue through measures such as:

1. No hardcoded secrets. Don't expect anything in the binaries (or data files) that you distribute to remain secret. If you need to store secrets somewhere, put them on the server and relay the query through it. This is a well-established best practice in security.
2. Don't try to authenticate the client software - that can always be
   spoofed - and instead authenticate the user (customers create
   accounts - indeed, you can charge for the account rather than the
   software itself - and abuse of accounts can result in them being
   blocked or charged extra).
3. Intellectual property protection is the business of the courts. Copyright, trade secret, and (if you must) patent laws are how you should prevent people from misappropriating your IP.
4. Consider software as a service (SaaS), where you run the program "in the cloud" and expose it to users via some thin interface, probably a web app. This limits what the software can do, increases your server costs considerably, and comes with its own large host of security risks (web security is hard). It also requires that the customers trust you to hold their data, and paints a giant target on your back because you are storing the data for every customer in one place. On the other hand, it makes it trivial to offer subscriptions for ongoing software access (rather than one-time sales) and trial accounts, which can help make sales more easily while providing an ongoing revenue stream. It lets customers access your software from any device with a browser and an Internet connection, which is popular. Finally, it basically eliminates risks of both piracy and reverse engineering (except in whatever part you offload to the client via client-side scripts, and of course static assets that are served to the client). Some very successful companies/products use this model (e.g. Salesforce, Google Docs, Slack, etc.).

Comment: This seems like a very good and thorough answer. But, you are probably doing this kid's homework for him...